# How to fetch private data with YQL on Yahoo PHP5 Sdk yos-social-php5

Tags: php, yahoo, yql, yahoo-api

I am using [Yahoo PHP5 SDK](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php5) and use it to fetch user contacts from table social.contacts which is a private data. On the example, from Delicious, it only shown fetching public data from YQL. May I know what parameter should I use to fetch private data with the class YahooYQLQuery and Execute()? I have tried to follow the example but following error message appear:

> YQL query failed with error: "Authentication Error. The table social.contacts requires a higher security level than is provided, you provided ANY but at least USER is expected".

Answer (score 2):

On the [YQL code examples page](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html#sdk_yql), the best example to walk through is the YQL Social Application. (The Delicious/OAuth stuff is obsolete now.)

Also, when [creating your Yahoo API key](https://developer.apps.yahoo.com/dashboard/createKey.html), make sure to select "This app requires access to private user data" and under Contacts, choose either Read or Read/Write, as appropriate for your app. This may be causing your YQL failure.

Comment: Hi Brian thanks for the reply.. The sdk that I am using now is the latest sdk, the deprecated sdk is https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php. Do you have any idea of referring the token to the class YahooYQLQuery and Execute()? as the example yql provided only referring to public data. Thanks..

Comment: I haven't personally run through these examples in a while, but in the [YQL code example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html#sdk_yql), the 'Querying Private Data' section should walk through the differences needed when going for **private** data like this.