# Get stock quotes from Yahoo finance

Tags: yql, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

I have been trying to fetch the stock quotes from Yahoo finance, but I have not been able to get that.

I have tried YQL Console, and it is working fine in that [https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+pm.finance+where+symbol%3D%22SBIN.BO%22.](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+pm.finance+where+symbol%3D%22SBIN.BO%22)

Here they are using **pm.finance** table to fetch the stock quote.

URL for accessing the REST URL it in browser [here](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20pm.finance%20where%20symbol%3D%22SBIN.BO%22&format=json&callback=)

If you will try to open the rest URL in the browser it gives you error:

*{"error":{"lang":"en-US","description":"Authentication Error.  The table pm.finance requires a higher security level than is provided, you provided ANY but at least APP is expected"}}*

So for this I created a Yahoo App for this, so that I will be able to access using CURL request
Created App on - https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/

But now I am not able to get how to use this app to make a CURL request and get the quotes.

I have also tried http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=sbin.bo&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv

But here I am not getting information about the quotes.

Please help me, how to get the stock quotes. I also know about Google finance API and have implemented that but client is specific about using Yahoo API.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an Yahoo! account? Even the simplest query `select * from pm.finance where symbol="YHOO"` returns the same result: **Authentication Error. The table pm.finance requires a higher security level than is provided, you provided ANY but at least APP is expected**. You'l need an Yahoo! account though. Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9203144/4092887) could help you more than my comment.

Comment: Yes I have yahoo account, and I have created the app also. But I guess the answer which you have tagged is not much use now, as it is of year 2012. I am stuck at how to use that app in making REST call so that yahoo consider me authenticated person. And I totally fine with the limits which they have applied.

Comment: @DASH use this instead of pm.finance `https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=` Do you able to solve the issue?

Comment: @behappy have you are tried the URL which you have commented, as I think Yahoo does not uses this table anymore. Regarding solving the issue, no I could not find any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo has discontinued their stock quote API.  Try the [Investor's Exchange API](https://iextrading.com/developer/docs/) instead.